# Editor with beamer environments/macros

Tags: beamer, texmaker, texstudio, kile

I am looking for a linux latex (not WYSWIG) editor, that includes beamer enhancements. Simple toolbars/shortcuts for inserting new frames, surrounding content in columns/overlays environments, etc. I tried kile, texstudio, texmaker and none of them seems to have anything beamer related, except creation of the initial document from a template.

Of course, I could spend time creating my own set of macros, but taking into account the popularity of beamer, I find it hard to believe that no such thing exists. Still, google did not return any good results.

Comment: I guess the community needs one to start the job and to spread it to all

Answer (score 3):

Up to now, it seems that only advanced editor (eg. Vim or Emacs) can fill your needs.

For Vim (with a plugin manager like `Vundle`) i recommend you these plugins:

- `ultisnips` (a snippets manager)
- `vim-snippets` (including beamer snippets)

For instance

```
frame<TAB>
```

produces

```
\begin{frame}[t]{title}

\end{frame}
```

You can also add LaTeX plugins like `vim-latex` to improve your productivity in Vim.

Comment: This kind of functionality for beamer is implemented in kile, texstudio, etc., but it is very restricted. Nothing implemented for columns, overlays and other more advanced (but still very basic!) beamer functions, not mentioning any kind of toolbar. Does those plugins for vim/emacs implement those more advanced functions?

Comment: The current snippets implemented are: frame, block, alertblock, exampleblock and two-column. `vim-snippets` is easy to configure: you need to edit a file named tex.snippets. The advantage of `vim-latex` is that you can type `env<F5>` and it creates the `begin{env}` and `end{env}` and it also includes all you need when you are typing LaTeX. I am not an expert for emacs. Someone else can help?

Comment: So, unfortunately, it implements just 5 environments out of many more, the same as other editors do, meaning that the beamer support is vestigial. I know that I can create my own snippets/macros even in the editors I am more used to, like kile and texstudio, but I am looking if anyone did it for me :) As there are many users of beamer around...